# Экраинирование кавычек

Tags: javascript, экранирование

C сайта получаю данные, которые могу содержать двойные или одинарные кавычки. Как их экранировать. Я шлю запрос например на https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KWLSe-UuOYE?alt=json&v=2

```
     var name = data.entry.title.$ //= содержит название "Киркорову нужно петь в психушке!" Жириновский! 26.02.2013

innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="reset" value="'+name+'"/>'
```

Comment: ajax ? тогда лучше json

Comment: В данном случае все верно! Единственное что, атрибут `class="reset` не закрыт двойной кавычкой, что видимо и вызывает конфликт!

Comment: да все равно, вот например я получил данные "Привет", получается, что оно вставляет value=""Привет""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = '"привет" как дела?';
str = str.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
html = '<input type="text" class="reset" value="'+str+'"/>';
document.write(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял проблему, попробуйте так:

```
name = name.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

Comment: теперь в value отображается только обратный слэш